# How to configure Internet access ONLY through OpenVPN connection

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

How to completely block access to the Internet directly, without OpenVPN?
All traffic must go through VPN connection, including DNS, TCP, UDP, etc.

I want to prevent any leaks that may occur due to Internet reconnection or any other technical problems.

I use the original OpenVPN client.
Tell me please the most reliable solution.

Also I would like to know how to turn off the IPv6.

Answer (score 2):

Also not an expert but long story short, it takes a couple of measures.

I've been using the following tool in combination with NordVPN, which seems to performs these measures automatically. 
https://github.com/Chadsr/NordVPN-NetworkManager

I'd advice you to look for clients specific for your vpn provider.

I'm hoping we'll get to a place where this is more integrated into the Network manager itself and or more providers create clients that support linux.

Answer (score 0):

#### Not an expert

You can use the VPN sections in the network settings menu to connect through an imported OpenVPN profile without the OpenVPN client.

You can disable your IPv6 address in your router config usually ( 192.168.1.1 )
You can disable it in the network settings > advanced options > ipv6 settings tab as well for another security layer?

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN settings seem to work the wrong way. The default is to force all traffic down the VPN. The option is to send only traffic to the VPN'd network down the VPN.

If you edit your VPN setting and click on the IPv4 tab (er, assuming you haven't moved to IPv6 yet) then you will see a "Routes" button near the bottom. Click on this. In the routes section you will see "Use this connection only for resources on its network" - clicking this will allow all traffic to the outside of the VPN to flow out through your local router but having it unselected will fource all of your traffic down the VPN.

[image: VPN Settings]